# How to divide a long sign up form in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a sign up form which has many fields and i want to divide it into three parts.I have heard of carousel sliders but have not seen for android.Can anyone tell me how to handle a sign up form with many fields?.Do you divide it into multiple activities or put all the fields in one single activity?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager

Comment: @Henry cant import the project into eclipse

Answer (score 0):

when you have a layout that contains many fields you have to put that layout itself into a scrollable client:

Here's my activity_create_character.xml layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_vertical"
    tools:context=".CreateCharacterActivity" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/create_character_activity_header_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/blank_space" />

        <!-- name -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivityNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" >
                <!-- important - remove this to make it scrollable -->
                <!-- <requestFocus /> -->

            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- gender -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivitySelectGenderGroup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivitySelectMaleButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/ultimahack_gender_male" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivitySelectFemaleButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ultimahack_gender_female" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- race (spinner) -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivityRaceSpinnerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- lots of more buttons and other widget -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivityCancelButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="abortCreation"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/createCharacterActivityConfirmButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="confirmCreation"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```